# Word for birth year and death year?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a deceased person is mentioned in a publication his or her name is often followed by parentheses and the year of birth and the year of death.  There is a single word describing that information.  What is that word?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware of a specialized term for this, but generically one could refer to it as their **lifespan**:

> the amount of time that a person or animal actually lives ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/life%20span))

Comment: In a similar vein: ***lifetime***.